# how can I identify a uibutton with the same tag id

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looping through an array and im using the index to tag my button id but there is a 1% chance two button tag id's can be the same when calling them.  How can I differentiate the two buttons when trying to call one of them with the same tag id?

```
 let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(MyVariables.SelectedChatLike) as! UIButton
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myImage.gif", ofType: nil)
 tmpButton.setImage(UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

sometimes the code above changes the wrong button image because two tags can be the same

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Refactor your program so that the button tag IDs are always unique. I can't tell you how to do that because your description is too vague.

BTW, if your images are in your bundle then just use imageNamed:

```
tmpButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"myImage.gif"), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through array index for 2 specific set of buttons, make sure u add add, say 1000 for one set of buttons, and for another set, add say 2000. 
So the two sets of buttons will be of tags [1000, 1001,1002...] and [2000,2001,2002...]